# Change #N/A to Blank cell

Tags: conditional-statements, formula, openoffice-calc

How can I change the `#N/A` to the blank cell if nothing in that cell?

```
Eg. =VLOOKUP(B19:B36;$TABLE.A1:C46;2;0)
```

I think I might need something like an `ISERROR` check but I don't 100% know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 8):

If we're talking about Excel 2010 and later you can use `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B19:B36;$TABLE.A1:C46;2;0);"")
```

You can also put text into the final string result

Comment: The question is misleading about the spreadsheet software as 2 different spreadsheets were stated in tags. However, it can be seen that the question is not about Excel. Absolute sheet referencing (`$` sign before the sheet name) is not possible in Excel. We also see *a dot* between the sheet name and the range, which is again not possible in Excel. Finally, in OpenOffice Calc there is [no IFERROR function](https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=92677). So the answer does not answer the question.

Comment: The formula above has a typo, I edited the answer but @miken32 rolled it back. Excel help page lists proper syntax. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611

Comment: @chris - it does not have a typo in the place that you mentioned. In fact, this is not a valid Excel syntax at all, but *not* because of what you offered to change. This is OpenOffice Calc! The answer itself **should be deleted** as there are no IFERROR in OpenOffice Calc. Your edit also did not make sense, because using commas or semicolons depends on Locale! Some areas use commas, some use semicolons. And you cannot have both of them in a formula - it is either commas or semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

The question was misleading about the spreadsheet software as 2 different spreadsheets were originally stated in tags. However, it can be seen that the question is about OpenOffice Calc:
 - Absolute sheet referencing (`$` sign before the sheet name) is not possible in Excel.
 - We also see *a dot* between the sheet name and the range, which is again not possible in Excel.

As [in OpenOffice Calc you don't have IFERROR function](https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=92677), the only way is to repeat your main function twice in the following form (you can use both, `ISNA` and `ISERROR`, but I suggest `ISNA` as it's more specific and fits your case):

```
=IF(ISNA(YourFormula);"";YourFormula)
```

In your case something like:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B19;$TABLE.A1:C46;2;0));"";VLOOKUP(B19;$TABLE.A1:C46;2;0))
```

You may want to make absolute reference to the range where you look for matching values, as I see you want to copy the formula down.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B19;$TABLE.$A$1:$C$46;2;0));"";VLOOKUP(B19;$TABLE.$A$1:$C$46;2;0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the cells will contain a formula this is about appearances, so Conditional formatting might suit, say if the cell background is white, for style choose Font > Font Effects > Font color `white`.

For this, select the relevant range - I have assumed D19:D36 - and Format > Conditional Formatting...  and for Condition 1 choose *Cell value is* and *equal to* and:

```
ISNA(D19)
```