# Index if in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-2010

I know this should be straightforward enough but i cannot make my head get round this.

I am looking to Index if in excel and cannot do it.

Basically, i have a working formula `=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,B:B,0))`

What i need is it to have a blank and not a `N/A` when there is no data further on in `A:A`

So, something like `=IF(A2>0) THEN INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,B:B,0)) OTHERWISE "")` would be perfect.

I have tried `=If(a2>0)--INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,B:B,0),"")`.

Comment: You can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526658/change-n-a-to-blank-cell

Comment: Thank you, i have tried all the options on that page but nothing is working

Comment: Is your data situation like the file INDEX_if_in_excel<https://www.dropbox.com/s/8969sddbyyjcorm/index_if_in_excel.xlsx?dl=0> uploaded by me  and the formula mentioned in this file serves your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we just look whether the INDEX function returns an error and keep the cell blank if that's the case? The formula would then look like

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,B:B,0))),"",INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,B:B,0)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, quite a few hours on this one but got there

Comment: This construct is exactly what the IFERROR function can do in a shorter way - `IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,B:B,0)), "")`. It returns the first argument if no error, and returns the second argument in case of any eror in the first argument.